# Rails: How to customize Devise signup to choose between sending or not sending confirmation email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I have a rails app where I want only `Users` with an activation code could get a confirmation email, otherwise they will just be registered and not get confirmation email.

Here is what I'm planning to do,  would this be something that would work ?

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
       if resource.activation_code == "ActivationCode"
         super
       else
         user = User.new(resource)
         user.skip_confirmation!
         user.save
       end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Solved it!

```
def create
   build_resource(sign_up_params)
   if resource.activation_code == "ActivationCode"
     super
   else
     user = User.new(sign_up_params)
     user.skip_confirmation!
     user.save
   end
end
```